# How long it will take to approve the tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I suggested two tag synonyms a week before, but it still shows **pending (0)**. Who will handle tag synonyms and will it have review queue and How long it will take to approve the tag synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there isn't a review queue for suggested tag synonyms, a tag synonym would be approved by:

- Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag when they visit the page showing the proposed synonyms.
- Moderators who visit https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all

In the former case, suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2; in the latter case, the approval is immediate.
In the first case, it is not possible to know when the suggested synonym will be approved, if it is approved.

As side note, tag synonyms are used when editing the questions using the *wrong* tag doesn't remove the tag from all the existing questions. That could be because the *wrong* tag is widely used before the community notices it, or because for X questions from which the tag is replaced with the correct tag, there are X+1 questions for which the tag is added. Another reason to use tag synonym is to replace the tags used in a Stack Exchange site with the correct tags used on *Drupal Answers*.

Since you suggested a tag synonym for a tag used once from a single user, I declined them. If you think that [ajax-commands](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax-commands) is not a tag that should be used, the tag can be edited out from the question; the same is true for [slide](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slide).

Comment: thanks for clarifying when to purpose the tag synonyms !!!